# How do I move the desktop icons around with the keyboard in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open **Ease of Access Center** by
   clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control
   Panel**, clicking **Ease of Access**, and
   then clicking **Ease of Access Center**.
2. Click **Make the mouse easier to use**.
3. Under **Control the mouse with the
   keyboard**, select the **Turn on Mouse
   Keys** check box.
4. Use the keys on the numeric keypad
   to move the mouse.
5. To **move the mouse pointer**: Press
   the arrow keys on the numeric keypad
   to move the pointer up, down, left,
   and right. Press the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>,
   <kbd>End</kbd>, and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys to move the
   pointer diagonally.
6. To **drag an item**: Move the pointer over the item you
   want to drag, and then pres <kbd>Ins</kbd>. Use
   the direction keys to move the item,
   and then press <kbd>Del</kbd> to drop the item
   where you want it to go.
7. To **click an item**: Move the
   pointer over the item you want to
   click, and then press <kbd>5</kbd>. To
   double-click an item, press the plus
   sign (<kbd>+</kbd>). To right-click an item,
   press the minus sign (<kbd>-</kbd>).

<sub>**PS**: You can also turn on Mouse Keys by pressing <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num Lock</kbd>.</sub>