# Can you move items on the desktop with the keyboard only?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, accessibility

Is it possible to move icons (files) on the desktop of Windows XP without touching the mouse, using the keyboard only?

**EDIT:** I am specifically interested in an answer that does not involve simply emulating the mouse.

Comment: Move them where?

Comment: Just around the desktop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No it is not possible.

The only way to move windows using your keyboard only is to use the "Move" command in the context menu on the title bar or task bar button. There is no "Move" command in the context menu of an icon on the desktop, neither is there an "Arrange Icons By" option.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? If I'm incorrect, help me out by showing me how. If you just don't like me, man up.

Comment: I downvoted because you admitted yourself that you're wrong on Stuart's answer.  You can do this out of the box with Mouse Keys.  Now that I see OP doesn't agree, though (to be fair, I think it IS an accurate answer to his question as worded) I'm not sure if I should retract or not. Hmmm.  EDIT: Nevermind, I can't unless you edit.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/330469/can-you-move-items-on-the-desktop-with-the-keyboard-only/330478#330478

Answer (score 13):

[Another Superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/118891/how-do-i-move-the-desktop-icons-around-with-the-keyboard-in-windows-7/118898#118898) shows the steps for Windows 7 - checking [Windows XP Accessibility](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/default.aspx) should cover any differences for XP.

Steps from other thread pasted below:

1. Open **Ease of Access Center** by
   clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control
   Panel**, clicking **Ease of Access**, and
   then clicking **Ease of Access Center**.
2. Click **Make the mouse easier to use**.
3. Under **Control the mouse with the
   keyboard**, select the **Turn on Mouse
   Keys** check box.
4. Use the keys on the numeric keypad
   to move the mouse.
5. To **move the mouse pointer**: Press
   the arrow keys on the numeric keypad
   to move the pointer up, down, left,
   and right. Press the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>,
   <kbd>End</kbd>, and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys to move the
   pointer diagonally.
6. To **drag an item**: Move the pointer over the item you
   want to drag, and then pres <kbd>Ins</kbd>. Use
   the direction keys to move the item,
   and then press <kbd>Del</kbd> to drop the item
   where you want it to go.
7. To **click an item**: Move the
   pointer over the item you want to
   click, and then press <kbd>5</kbd>. To
   double-click an item, press the plus
   sign (<kbd>+</kbd>). To right-click an item,
   press the minus sign (<kbd>-</kbd>).

<sub>**PS**: You can also turn on Mouse Keys by pressing <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num Lock</kbd>.</sub>

Comment: Well I'll be darned.

Comment: This doesn't really count, sorry. It's just a way to control the mouse (with abysmal efficiency) using the keyboard.

Comment: @Ram Rachum - It answers the question of "Is it possible to move icons (files) on the desktop of Windows XP without touching the mouse, using the keyboard only?"  Just because you don't LIKE it (and I don't either, it's clunky and not entirely with the spirit of what I think you probably meant) doesn't mean it doesn't COUNT.

Comment: @Ram Rachum - it would help a lot if you gave some context to your question.  I can't for the life of me think why you would want to use keyboard-only to move desktop icons around, apart from an accessibility point of view, but from your comment against my answer it doesn't appear that's your reason.

Comment: If you wore gloves and manipulated your mouse with them, you would also technically not touch the mouse and it would be a technically legitimate answer, but I expect people to have some common sense.

Comment: @Ram Rachum I'll refer you to my previous comment.  If you're not happy with the responses, then edit your question to reflect what you actually want to know.

Comment: @Stuart McLaughin: Accessibility is indeed the reason. I don't see how your answer is accessibility-relevant. The "Mouse Keys" approach is on the same comfort level as grabbing the mouse with your mouth, moving it and clicking it with your teeth.

Comment: @Ram Rachum Apart from the fact that my answer utilises the 'Ease of Access Center.  From Microsoft: "The Ease of Access Center is a central location that you can use to set up the accessibility settings and programs available in Windows".  I still have no idea what you are trying to achieve and as Shinrai said, you've received an answer to your question and there doesn't appear to be any alternatives, so the short answer to your question is 'Yes' but since you don't like that answer, it's 'No'.

Comment: @Stuart McLaughin: Just because something has the word "Accessibility" on it doesn't make it more accessible. The reason that people prefer the keyboard over the mouse is because it's so much faster and efficient, for both able and disabled people-- Which is exactly what the "Mouse Keys" approach is not. This is why this answer is not helpful. If your answer was the only one, I would say that the answer is "No, you can't do that with the keyboard."

Comment: @Ram Rachum - I would say that your definition of "can" and "can't" needs a bit of modification.  I would say you can't do it *in such a manner that it's worthwhile, unless you have no other options*.  Just saying that you can't implies that it's completely impossible, which is clearly not the case.  The answer is valid though, and if you ever for whatever reason absolutely had to move some icons and you had no pointing device available, this would be your only solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a very inefficient trick!

You'll need to know that <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> allows you to open right-click context menu (call it *CM* for short). For best effect you'll need the following options to be set like so:

- Uncheck "CM > View > Auto arrange icons"
- Check "CM > View > Align icons to grid"

Now follow this series of steps, mix it up, add in some delete steps until you get the desired the result:

1. Put an item on the desktop (e.g. "CM > New > Text Document", hopefully the icon you want to move is already there.)
2. Select a random item using Down-Arrow key, then navigate to the item you want to move using arrow keys.
3. Push <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the item onto your clipboard.
4. Push <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> several times to fill up your desktop with that icon.
5. Locate the icon at the location you want, then delete the others.
6. Rename the file you want to keep ("CM > Rename")

Basically you can treat the desktop as a *table of icons*. After filling it, you delete the cells that you don't want.

You can re-select the desktop after having an item selected by deleting something. You should copy something then delete it to use this trick.

Comment: that ... is sketchy ... beyond measure. I like it!